# jQuery count div that has display:block

Tags: jquery

I have div elements as shown in image below. I want count of divs that has css display as block.

What I tried:

1)    `$('div.price_listing_container:visible').length`

and

2.)

```
  $('#content').children("div").filter(function() {
        return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';
  }).length
```

and

3.)    `$("#content > div").filter(":block").size()`

Last option didn't worked at all, other two work in alert but if I assign their returned value to a variable the value comes 0, not sure why is it so, See the code below:

```
var numberOfResultsVisible =  ($('#content').children("div").filter(function() {
                return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';
            }).length);
```

and

```
var numberOfResultsVisible =  $('div.price_listing_container:visible').length;
```

After assignment value comes 0.

Can you please tell if I can use some other method to get the count.

[image]

Comment: "other two work in alert but if I assign their returned value to a variable the value comes 0, not sure why is it so." - post the code that wasn't working, this seems like it **should** work correctly.

Comment: Calling `alert(numberOfResultsVisible);` directly after either of those two lines returns 0?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Yes. I tried both and did alert after value assignment and value comes 0

Comment: _"Other two work in alert"_ - are you saying `alert($('div.price_listing_container:visible').length)` shows a non-zero value if placed in the same spot in the code as your `var numberOfResultsVisible = ...` line?

Comment: That's odd, because it works fine for me. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LynRq/1/).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Could be the problem because I am putting these divs dynamically at run time so when count is firing divs are not loaded by then. But I have put this code in $(document).ready(function(){}); and also am calculating total count of divs which is working fine.

Comment: @Sandy That might explain it. Selectors aren't dynamic, they reflect the state of the DOM when they were run. If the elements don't exist when you call that line of code then the length will be `0`. However, you stated that simply alerting the value **did** provide the correct result, so I'm not sure that's the issue; the two should be the same.

Comment: If the divs are added (or their styles are changed) dynamically then you need to get the `$('div.price_listing_container:visible').length` _after_ the changes are made. If you need that count in a variable you need to assign it _after_ the changes. Where was the `alert()` that you said worked?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Putting code in a method and calling that method with setTimeout worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

how about a simple loop?

```
$(function(){
    var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++)
    {
        var thisElem = allElems[i];
        if (thisElem.style.display == 'block') count++;
    }
    alert(count);
});
```

Same here:
http://jsfiddle.net/E252r/8/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#content').find("div:visible").length
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E252r/2/

Comment: @Curt: Getting error "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [style=display:none]"

Comment: @Sandy Sorry hadn't tested. Needed speech marks. Fixed post. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/E252r/

Comment: This does the opposite of what the question asked for, though - he wants visible elements (`style="display: block"`), this code selects hidden elements (`style="display: none"`). The space after the colon may also cause problems.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist My mistake, changed for only elements which are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

don't inline styles - add another class:

```
 <div class="price_listing_container plblock"> ...
```

Then you can filter them using:

```
 $('#content div.price_listing_container.plblock')
```

in your css you'd have:

```
 div.plblock {display:block;}
```

This is a much cleaner method.

Comment: look at the code in the OP: "I have div elements as shown in the image below" - all with in-line styles

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#content').children('div:visible').length
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`getComputedStyle()`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0440__Style/GetComputedStyle.htm) property. I heard it's unavailable in IE which probably has its own alternative function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var display = $("#content").attr("style");
if(display.text(style) == "display:none")
  {

  } else {

  }
```

Comment: That's both invalid syntax and not what the question asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You said it worked on alert than try this where you do alert

```
//alert($('div.price_listing_container:visible').length);
var myVar;
eval('myVar = '+$('div.price_listing_container:visible').length+';');
```

When you assign any thing to new variable it shares the reference, and if the value of referenced memory is changed than the new variable is also changed. by this code it will not happen.

Comment: The `.length` property returns an integer (number primitive), not an object, so there is no sharing references involved here.

Comment: @nnnnnn so can you please explain how the numberOfResultsVisible has been 0.

Comment: According to the comment the OP just posted above he was trying to run the code _before_ the DOM was ready at which point the count actually was 0. He says the same code in a document ready handler works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... i just tested it

```
    length = $('div[style~="display:block;"]').size();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me as well:

```
$('#content').children('div:visible').length
$('#content').children('div:hidden').length
```