# Count divs with CSS style set to display: flex (not inline) and output the counted number in div as text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This question is a party duplicate of an answer in [jQuery count div that has display:block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611744/jquery-count-div-that-has-displayblock). I changed `getElementsByTagName` to `getElementsByClassName` and `block` to `flex` in the -if- statement.

Because I need the following functionality: Count the divs that are set with style display: flex in a separate stylesheet, so not inline, and then output the number count in a div; when the count is “0” output should be 0 in text, else the correct number of counted divs.

I am a beginner in Javascript and don’t know how I should continue.

Thank you.

```js
$(function(){
    var allElems = document.getElementsByClassName('displayflex');
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++) 
    {
        var thisElem = allElems[i];
        if (thisElem.style.display == 'flex') count++;
    }
    alert(count);
});
```

```css
.displayflex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    <div class="displayflex"></div>
    <div class="displayflex"></div>
    <div class="displayflex"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id="outputnumber"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is that the `style` attribute only reads inline styles. You will need to look at the [computed styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) of each element to see styles applied via CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `style` attribute only reads inline styles. You will need to look at the [computed styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) of each element to see styles applied via CSS.

Here using the appropriate [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) and [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) declarations for variables, a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop for brevity, and updating the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext) of the relevant div with the result.

```js
$(function () {
  const allElems = document.getElementsByClassName('displayflex');
  
  let count = 0;
  for (const elem of allElems) {
    const compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
    if (compStyles.getPropertyValue('display') === 'flex') {
      count++;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('outputnumber').textContent = count;
});
```

```css
.displayflex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
    <div class="displayflex"></div>
    <div class="displayflex"></div>
    <div class="displayflex"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div id="outputnumber"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and clarification of the code! I hope your code will help others with a similar question/issue in the future too.

Answer (score 0):

You need computed style like below

```
$(function(){
    var allElems = document.getElementsByClassName('displayflex');
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++) 
    {
        var thisElem = allElems[i];
        if (window.getComputedStyle(thisElem, null).display == 'flex') count++;
    }
    alert(count);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Count div</title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <style>
   .displayflex {
      display: flex;
    }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   
    <div id="content">
      <div class="displayflex"></div>
      <div class="displayflex"></div>
      <div class="displayflex"></div>
      <div class="displayflex"></div>
      <div></div>
   </div>

    <div id="outputnumber"></div>
    <script>
        $('#outputnumber').html($('.displayflex').length);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```